# Display smallest even and odd number from six integers without using loops and arrays

Tags: c++, logic

So I am trying to do an assignment for my class but for some reason I cant get the output to match with what I need. I have to make a program that asks for 6 integers and display the smallest even and odd. There will be 3 even entered and 3 odd but the order is unknown and we can't use loops or arrays. This sample is just what i have so far but I can't seem to understand why a and b won't work.

```
int a, b, c, d, e, f, smallEven=0, smallOdd=0;
cout<<"Enter a number:\n";
cin>>a;

if (a%2==0)
    smallEven=a;
else if (a%2==1)
    smallOdd=a;

cout<<"Enter a number:\n";
cin>>b;

if (b%2==0)
    if (smallEven=0)
        smallEven=b;
    else if (b<smallEven)
        smallEven=b;
else if (b%2==1)
    if (smallOdd=0)
        smallOdd=b;
    else if (b<smallOdd)
        smallOdd=b;

cout<<smallEven;
cout<<smallOdd;
```

Comment: Here: `if (smallEven=0)` you must use a comparison, not an assigment. I.e: `if (smallEven==0)`. Same for `if (smallOdd=0)`

Comment: You really should be compiling with warnings that'll tell you when you write `=` instead of `==`.  Try adding the command-line switches `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion`. If you can't for some reason, mitigations include: always putting the constant on the **left** of the equality (`0=smallEven` would be caught as an error.) Or declare a series of `const` variables that are initialized only once and never changed. The compiler will then realize if you're assigning a second time by mistake. Or you can replace the loop with tail-recursion.

Comment: You could also simplify your code by initializing `smallEven` and `smallOdd` with the largest possible value (`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`). Then you don't need to test for 0. You can use the same piece of code six times.

Comment: The logic of your code isn't working because you're using `=` rather than `==`.  The effects are crucially different.   Apart from that, replicating code (by copy and paste and updating a variable name each time) is a POOR solution to the problem - if the person marking the exercise is at all credible, such an approach deserves no more than half marks even it it works.   Consider putting repeated logic into a function, and call that function as many times as needed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this isn't doing what you're expecting is that you're using an assignment operator (=) instead of the comparison operator for equality (==) in two places:

```
if (b%2==0)
    if (smallEven=0)   // should be == here
        smallEven=b;
    else if (b<smallEven)
        smallEven=b;
else if (b%2==1)
    if (smallOdd=0)    // should be == here
        smallOdd=b;
    else if (b<smallOdd)
        smallOdd=b;
```